# Read local files into spark dataframe in zeppelin running on a docker container

Tags: docker, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to write Spark code in Zeppelin using apache [zeppelin docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/zeppelin/) on my laptop. Everything works as expected except reading files from local disk, e.g. when I try to read a csv file into a Spark dataframe

`val df = spark.read.csv("/User/myname/documents/data/xyz.csv")`

I get the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/User/myname/documents/data/xyz.csv;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:382)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:370)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:415)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:352)
  ... 47 elided
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer:
I pulled the docker image (I used the one below but you can change it)

`docker pull skymindops/zeppelin-dl4j`

And then ran:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 7077:7077 -p 8080:8080 --privileged=true -v $PWD/logs:/logs -v $PWD/notebook:/notebook -v $PWD/data:/data \
-e ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR='/notebook' \
-e ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR='/logs' \
skymindops/zeppelin-dl4j:latest
```

Now reading files from data folder will work:

`val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("/data/xyz.csv")`

Note that I didn't need the notebooks already in that image.